# Python Build Script

Tags: python, build

What are some best practices for creating a build script for a Python project?  Specifically, not for building a Python library, but a Python application (e.g. standalone server app or web app).  What are some frameworks out there that support:

- Managing dependencies for different environments (dev, test, prod, etc.)
- Running tasks: start, stop, test, pydoc, pep8, etc.
- Preparing for deployment with a virtualenv: creating a package (tar.gz, rpm, egg, etc.)

I usually use setuputils/easy_install for doing this -- which has it's limitations.  However, I read an article saying one should use distutils/pip.  Which if these is more robust? Are there any other choices?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a good building framework, [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) which is python based is a good make substitute.

Comment: Does it allow one to manage Python package dependencies?  Install them if they are not there, etc.?

Comment: Haven't looked at that.  I've used it mainly as a make replacement for C++ projects.  But SCons is just python scripts with some special imports so it can do anything python can do...